# How to display a specified section or line from a huge file without loading the whole file into memory?

Tags: linux, vim, ubuntu, gedit

I am trying to debug a large (1.1Gb) SQL dump file. The file says there was an error on line 14718. I have tried opening the file in VIM and gedit but the file was too big to load. Is there a quick way to get a small piece of the file so that I can correct the error and save the file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nick, not sure if this will, help, but I always end up using `less`.

Give this a try and let me know if it helps:

```
less +j14718 -N aFile.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm using Geany to parse very large files. (like your sql dump)

It runs under Linux, FreeBSD, NetBSD, OpenBSD, MacOS X, AIX, Solaris Express and Windows.

And it's GPL: http://www.geany.org/

(you may find it in most linux distribuitions as an IDE)